# How do I test that external CSS does not contain an absolute URL via unit test?

Tags: selenium, css

I have been given the task of validating that we do not have any http:// URLs in our CSS or HTML documents. I've created a selenium IDE test that looks at src & href attributes as well as script tags for http: but I'm not sure how to test a style sheet.

As I'm not trying to test specific selectors, it could be in any attribute in the document.  For instance, a random div tags background:

I've thought about putting this in java and attempting to pull resources and parse them, but that seems a bit over the top.

Comment: Welcome to SQA, Lucas.  Do you need to worry about Javascript-induced changes, or is a static analysis good enough?

Comment: JavaScript would be nice to have, but not necessary.

Comment: How about creating a simple script in bash/Perl that lists all occurences of such incorrect resources? e.g. `cat *.css |  grep 'http://'`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the flat files because they're a resource served as part of a custom CMS product for university giving.  As users change the CSS, the URL to the CSS changes.  Otherwise, that's a great idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a regular expression for URLs (you should be able to find a few online), and search for the pattern in your HTML or CSS file.  You just need to read the file in to a String (break it if the file is too long), and try pattern matching.  You can do this without the overhead of Selenium or any other testing tool if you are familiar with either of Perl, Python, Bash, Ruby, etc. or just use Java.

Comment: Interesting idea, but the CSS files happen to be included within a CMS like product.  I don't have file system access to them.  They also get included as part of components within the CMS and have changing file names.

Comment: I guess then you can use Selenium to get the text from the css file, and use regex for search/match.

Comment: @Lucas, is CSS stored in HTML file or in external files referenced in HTML file?

Comment: The CSS is stored in external files (using link tag).

Comment: So Suchit's comment should work. You just need first to parse out all links to CSS with Selenium, regepx or XPath, and then for each extracted link, fetch the referenced CSS file (e.g. with 'wget' in Perl).

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone.  It's a windows server, so I'll have to do some convincing to get some gnu tools. :)

Comment: There are lots of Windows tools not requiring GNU that you may use. Java has support for that, Perl cannot be installed as well. Specify a language (in question) in which you want to get the answer.